# Ngrx selector not triggering updates

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

My state is :

```
export interface RequestState {
  tabsContent: TabContent[];
}
```

Where `TabContent` represent an array of visual tabs containing 1 Request each and additionnal infos :

```
export interface TabContent {
  tabInfo: TabInfo;
  request: Request;
  results?: any[];
}
```

I have this specialized selector to get one Request from a single TabContent :

```
export const getRequestForTabInfo = (tabInfo: TabInfo) => createSelector(
  getTabContent,
  (tabContent: TabContent[]) => {
    const tabContentFiltered = tabContent.filter(tab =>
      tab.tabInfo.id === tabInfo.id
      && tab.tabInfo.index === tabInfo.index
      && tab.tabInfo.state === tabInfo.state);
    if (tabContentFiltered && tabContentFiltered.length === 1) {
      return tabContentFiltered[0].request;
    }
    return {} as Request;
  },
);
```

and this basic one to get all TabsContent :

```
export const getTabContent = createSelector(
  getRequestFeatureState,
  state => state.tabsContent,
);
```

based on this FeatureSelector :

```
const getRequestFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<RequestState>('requests');
```

Defined in a facade service :

```
tabsContent$: Observable<TabContent[]>;
constructor(private store: Store<fromRequest.State>) {
    this.tabsContent$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRequest.getTabContent),
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroy()),
    );
}
  public getRequest(tabInfo: TabInfo): Observable<Request> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRequest.getRequestForTabInfo(tabInfo)),
      takeUntil(this.componentDestroy()),
    );
  }
```

and used in the component :

```
private initializeComponent(): void {
        this.requestFacade.getRequest(this.tabInfo).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.componentDestroy()),
        ).subscribe(request => {
          console.log('request : ', request);
          this.request = request;
        });
        this.requestFacade.tabsContent$.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.componentDestroy()),
        ).subscribe(tab => {
          console.log('tab : ', tab);
        });
}
```

When the component is consctructed I get both logs, but when I update part of the related state (I update the content of one Request) only the `tab` log appear.

Why is the filtered selector observable not doing anything ?

Comment: Because your input argument(tabInfo) hasn't changed, so it is not emitting any new value. Try changing the input argument after updating a relevant part of the state and check whether its working.

Comment: Of course after changing the input argument of the selector (tabInfo) it's triggering. But that's not how it should work, changes to the state should trigger it. My selector is not supposed to change

Answer (score 1):

You're using a static parameter in the getRequestForTabInfo selector so it presumes that it will not change overtime, which is why you are not getting the changes.

Instead of passing in parameters, I would suggest dispatching an action to set the selected tabinfo in the store and use selectors to retrieve it.  You already have TabContents in store so should be able to reuse some of the logic you've already have.